# Why is [ "$foo"=="$bar" ] always true in bash?

Tags: bash, string-comparison

I tried to compare user input between to string
Here is my code

```
Encode="Encode"
Decode="Decode"

printf "Enter name of file: "
read fileName
printf "Encode Or Decode: "
read EncOrDec

if [ "$Encode"=="$EncOrDec" ]; then
    printf "Encode Nice\n"
elif [ "$Decode"=="$EncOrDec" ]; then
    printf "Decode Nice\n"
else
    printf "Nothing\n"
fi
```

Its always go to the Encode statement, Why?.
And how to fix it

Comment: This issue will be automatically detected by http://shellcheck.net/; consider making a habit of running code through there before asking questions here.

Comment: BTW, when trying to write a question title, try to describe the specific problem as much as possible -- ie. not just "issue with X", but "Why is X doing Y when Z is expected?". I've attempted to edit towards that end here; that way folks can see at a glance if they have the same problem (if the question is answered), or if they're likely to be able to help (if not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, spaces count.  Replace:

```
if [ "$Encode"=="$EncOrDec" ]; then
```

With:

```
if [ "$Encode" = "$EncOrDec" ]; then
```

Without spaces, bash is just testing whether the string `"$Encode"=="$EncOrDec"` is empty or not.  Since it is *never* empty, the `then` clause is always executed.

Also, as a minor detail, when using `[...]`, the use of `=` for string equality is POSIX standard.  Bash accepts `==` but `==` is not standard and won't be reliably portable.

The same applies to the `elif` line.  Replace:

```
elif [ "$Decode"=="$EncOrDec" ]; then
```

With:

```
elif [ "$Decode" = "$EncOrDec" ]; then
```